# Segmentation fault while using vector of sets in C++

Tags: c++, vector, set, codeblocks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
vector< set< int > > A;
A[0].insert(1);
A[0].insert(2);
}
```

When i run above ode on Codeblocks ,I get segmentation fault.Can anyone answer why am i getting this error and solution to avoid segmentation fault in this code.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` don't do that!

Comment: First of all, please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Secondly, when you create your vector, it is *empty!*. All indexing will be out of bounds. Perhaps you need to take a step back, [get a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and start over?

Answer (score 5):

Since `A` is an empty vector, `A[0]` does not refer to a valid object. So you shouldn't be calling `insert` on it.

Answer (score 1):

the Vector A , is empty before you invoke it,
so it is illegal to invoke A[0] ;
insert something before .